# How to get cucumber running in selenium nightwatch framework

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have got the same prob:
I am working on a project where scripts were already developed by someone. I find it difficult to integrate cucmber now. Can someone please guide?

Below is the steps.js and nightwatch.conf.js files:
Issue: Nightwatch is running. However, i dont see Cucumber running. There is no 'Given, When, Then' scenarios getting displayed in the cmd prmpt.

**nightwatch.conf.js:**

```
module.exports = function(){
require('nightwatch-api')({
  cucumberArgs: [
      '--require',
      'steps-definitions',
      '--format',
      'node_modules/cucumber-pretty',
      '--require',
      'cucumber.conf.js',
      'Features/Main.feature'
  ]
});
}
  module.exports = (function(settings) {
  settings.selenium.server_path = require('selenium-server-standalone-jar').path;
  settings.selenium.cli_args['webdriver.chrome.driver'] = require('chromedriver').path
  return settings;
})(require('./nightwatch.json'));
```

Steps.js file:

```
const { client } = require('nightwatch-api');
const { Given, When, Then } = require('cucumber');


Given(/^I open Google`s search page$/,function () {
  return client
  .url('http://google.com')
  //.waitForElementVisible('body', 1000);
});

When('the title is "Google"', function (text) {
  await client.assert.title(text);
});

Then('the Google search form exists', function () {
  await client.assert.visible('input[name="q"]');
});
```

**Nightwatch.json**

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "pages",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "",
    "log_path" : "",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.edge.driver" : ""
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "https://aem-staging-uk.stcdev.com/",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "path" : "./screenshots",
        "on_failure": true,
        "on_error": true
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts" : true,
        "chromeOptions" : {
          "args" : ["--no-sandbox", "--window-size=1920,1080", "--no-gpu"]
         }
      }
    },
    "staging":{
      "launch_url" : "https://staging.stcdev.com/"
    },
    "qa6.3":{
      "launch_url" : "https://aem-qa1-uk.stcdev.com/"
    },
    "staging6.3":{
      "launch_url" : "https://aem-staging-uk.stcdev.com/"
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing nightwatch-cucumber. I will try to provide more details later if you still need help.

Comment: Nightwatch-cucumber requires nightwatch@0.9.0 - 0.9.21